# How can I connect 2 nodes and send data over them using python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python script which creates a variable `heading`. I want to transmit this heading to another node in a wireless ad-hoc network.

I have looked at a lot of tutorials and examples but I don't quite understand which end is which for the sockets.

I think on the node I have created the variable I would have code something like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((ipv4_address, 50086))
s.send(heading)
```

And on the receiving end I would want something listening on the same port waiting for the heading to arrive:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((ipv4_address, 50086))
while 1:
    data = client_socket.recv(512)
```

I'm not sure if I am getting the connect and bind the right way around?

Answer (score 1):

- The server part must perform the sequence `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`. Your server part currently doesn't `listen` to a socket and doesn't `accept` connections. Also the server part should `recv` data from the socket returned by `accept`, but not the one that you're listening to.
- You need to ensure that `heading` variable is a string. Otherwise you might want to use [`JSON`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module to serialize your objects.

I'd suggest you to read the [`socket module examples`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) at official Python documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if `pickle` is the right thing for sending data over the wire, especially when the server must suspect that anyone could have connected...

Comment: @Alexey Is there any advantage over using json/pickle?

Comment: @Alexey also - and this is a really stupid question - but the server is the receiving end?

Comment: @markmcmurray The server is the end that listens to connections. If I'm not wrong, it may both send and receive. And the client is the side that initiates the connection.

Comment: @markmcmurray Regarding the advantages of json/pickle. I think it depends on your task. Pickle is perfect for networks you trust only as it isn't secure (as glglgl correctly notes). JSON should be the right solution for services to operate over the Internet.

Comment: @Alexey. Ok, this is something that has confused me looking at all the examples. How can I ensure that the server end is always listening to the socket as well as I want the heading to be transmitted every time the heading changes which could be whenever.

Comment: @markmcmurray For that you should make a loop that does `listen()`, `accept()` and passes socket returned by `accept()` to a new thread that does all the server-side communication.